# How to strip and rebuild an existing branch and push it to the main repository? (aka replace a branch with a new one)

Tags: mercurial, branch, push, dvcs

THE CONTEXT:

There are three branches: "mine" and "yours" and "main". I started with a clean clone and the only requirement is to make the "mine" branch like the "main" branch with only a few added changes. I do not want to alter the other branches. The current "mine" branch has only one changeset that I would prefer to delete and replace with a new changeset.

MY ATTEMPT:

"mine" contains only one changeset, which I want to discard. So, I stripped this changeset(effectively deleting "mine"), updated directory to "main" branch, recreated "mine" ("hg branch mine"), added my changes, committed, and now I want to push. The output of "hg push -b mine" is "abort: push creates new remote head..." and references my new changeset. However, I just want to replace my new changeset with my old (locally deleted) changeset. "hg outgoing" lists my new changeset, "hg incoming" lists my old changeset.

I think I am very close, any suggestions? Would a forced push work here? Alternative solutions and helpful references are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

After my attempt, which involved stripping the changesets that I did not want from the "mine" branch and then committing my new changesets on the "mine" branch, here is my solution:

I resolved this issue with a forced push "hg push -f" which thus created two heads on the "mine" branch (in the main repository), and then stripped the extra head using the "hg strip" extension. This was done from the main repository after I had pushed, which may not be perfect, but it worked for these purposes.

The forced push was needed to add my new changesets (the new "mine" branch) and the strip (which had to be done after the push, on the main repository) deleted the old "mine" branch. It turns out that stripping the "mine" branch in my local repository doesn't make a difference because the stripped changesets are still present on the main repository (thus the need to strip them after the push).

If there is a better solution (or a better way to phrase the question), I am curious to find out.

Comment: FYI: If you had stripped it from the main repo first, you shouldn't have needed the `-f` switch. Wish I had better answer for you...